# Access text from UITextField in modal View Controller from Home View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a `ViewController1` with a `UILabel` that can present a `ViewController2` with a Modal Segue. I have a `UITextField` in `ViewController2` that I need to access from `ViewController1` so I can set my `UILabel` with the collected text.

I've tried working with the `prepareForSegue` without success. What should I do?

EDIT:

I'm using a Delegate, but I'm doing something wrong. Here's the code I'm using in `ViewController2.h`:

```
@class ViewController2;

@protocol VCProtocol

-(void)setName:(NSString *)name;

@end

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<VCProtocol> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *nameField;

- (IBAction)setButton:(id)sender

@end
```

`ViewController2.m`

```
-(IBAction)setButton:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate setName:nameField.text];
}
```

I conform to `VCProtocol` in my `ViewController1.h`. Then, in my `ViewController1.m`, I have this code:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)name
{
    self.firstSignatureNameLabel.text = name;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"Sign"])
    {
        ViewController2 *VC = [segue destinationViewController];
        VC.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want it to be accessible to every view, you need to create a Model/Data class. The question is not a duplicate, but the answer applies from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6067515/2535467). [This question might be more like yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228242/how-to-access-string-variable-in-one-view-controller-to-another-view-controller)

Comment: This is what delegates are for. VC1 should set itself as the delegate of VC2 when it does the presentation. VC2 should define a protocol with a single method that you would call on the delegate in the text field's action method.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol and set VC1 as delegate of VC2, and using `prepareForSegue` to set VC1 as VC2's delegate should work. I know that you said it didn't work, but I can't see why. Have a try with this :

Give an identifier to your segue (on storyboard), and implement `prepareForSegue` as shown below :

VC2Delegate.h :

```
@protocol VC2Delegate
    - (void)updateLabel:(NSString *)text;
@end
```

VC1.h :

```
#import "VC2Delegate.h"
@interface VC1 : UIViewController <VC2Delegate>
    // All your stuff
@end
```

VC1.m :

```
- (void)updateLabel:(NSString *)text {
    [_label setText:text];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"YourSegueIdentifier"]) {
        VC2 * vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc2 setDelegate:self];
    }
}
```

VC2.h :

```
#import "VC2Delegate.h"
@interface VC2 : UIViewController
    @property (weak, nonatomic) id<VC2Delegate>delegate;
@end
```

VC2.m

```
- (void)textWasUpdated { // or whatever method where you detect the text has been changed
    if (_delegate)
        [_delegate updateLabel:[_textView text]];
}
```

Tell me if it works. Else, is prepareForSegue even been called ?

EDIT : Updated my answer (wasn't exactly what you needed).
But as you say it doesn't work :

- Is prepareForSegue called ?
- If so, is the delegate method called ?
- If the delegate method isn't called, check that delegate is not `nil`.

You might want to remove the segue, and present it modally by yourself, using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`, like that :

```
- (IBAction)buttonWasTapped {
    static NSString * const idModalView = @"modalView";
    static NSString * const storyBoardName = @"MainStoryBoard"
    UIStoryboard * storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName bundle:nil];
    VC2 * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:idModalView];
    [vc setDelegate:self];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:vc2 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I'll try this, @DCMaxxx and let you know what happens.

Answer (score -2):

When [I ran into this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405636/obj-c-how-to-pass-data-between-viewcontrollers-using-a-singleton), I chose the singleton approach and it works.